# Print line every four lines from an file

Tags: awk, csh

I have a file that contains 8000 lines, I want to print lines 1,4,8,12,...,7996.

I tried this code

```sh
for j in {1 .. 8000}
do
k= $((4 * $j))
print k 
sed -n $k P test.dat >> test.dat1 
done
```

but this error appears:

> ./test.csh: line 3: 4 * {1: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "{1")

what is the problem, how can I do this?

Comment: The error message indicates that you are using `csh`, not Bash. These are fundamentally different languages.

Comment: If you want every 4th line starting from the first, the sequence is 1, 5, 9, 13, ...

Comment: Avoid at all cost the usage of _csh_. It is broken, buggy and just flawed. [Top 10 reasons not to use C shell](http://www.grymoire.com/unix/CshTop10.txt) and [csh programming considered harmfull](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/shell/csh-whynot/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `awk` command:

```
awk 'NR%4==1{print}' input.txt
```

#### Explanation:

```
NR % 4 == 1 { # for every input line, which line number (NR) modulo 4 is 1
    print $0; # print the line
}
```

Comment: @David But that will print when the modulo is 2 or 3, too.

Comment: Oh, correct you are -- I knew the coffee had worn off by then.... I actually think you need `awk 'NR==1 || NR%4==0'` to match `1, 4, 8, 12, 16, ...` Here is a quick test you can run `printf "%s\n" {1..20} | awk 'NR==1 || NR%4==0'` If you are not on bash, use `$(seq 1 20)` instead of the *brace-expansion*.

Comment: The reason I say that is right now you match `1, 5, 9, 13, ...`

Comment: To make this a bit smaller: `awk 'NR%4==1' file`. awk works with `pattern { action }` pairs. If a pattern is written, then the default action is `print $0`.

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer `sed`

```
sed -n '0~4p'
```

Interesting enough, this is the exact sample shown in `man sed`

> 'FIRST~STEP'
>        This GNU extension matches every STEPth line starting with line
>        FIRST.  In particular, lines will be selected when there exists a
>        non-negative N such that the current line-number equals FIRST + (N
>        * STEP).  Thus, one would use '1~2' to select the odd-numbered
>        lines and '0~2' for even-numbered lines; to pick every third line
>        starting with the second, '2~3' would be used; to pick every fifth
>        line starting with the tenth, use '10~5'; and '50~0' is just an
>        obscure way of saying '50'.
>
> ```
>  The following commands demonstrate the step address usage:
>
>       $ seq 10 | sed -n '0~4p'
>       4
>       8
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be attempting to use Bash syntax even though your question is tagged [csh](/questions/tagged/csh).

Even so, this has multiple errors. You can't have a space after the assignment operator, and you need to quote the `sed` script (otherwise it thinks `P` is the first file name ... Or I guess you actually mean `p`).

But the idea that you need to loop over the file 8000 times and print one line out of it in each iteration is also flawed. You can tell `sed` to print every fourth line with a single script like

```
sed -n -e 1p -e 5p -e 9p ... filename
```

I would switch to Awk for this, though.

```
awk 'FNR%4==1' filename
```

Comment: Friends don't let friends use [tag:csh] so maybe this is a step in the right direction.